# Comparing graphs in mathematica: shape vs. name

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks, filtering

I'm trying to identify and remove duplicate graphs when contracting vertices. To illustrate this, I'll start with two simple graphs where I'm trying to create a function that can recognize them as duplicates.

```
graphList = {Graph[
    Range[3], { 1  \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
    VertexLabels -> Automatic, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"], 
   Graph[Range[3], {1  \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
    VertexLabels -> Automatic, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]};
contractEdgeList = {{1, 2}, {{2, 3}}};
res = MapThread[
  VertexContract[#1, #2] &, {graphList, contractEdgeList}]
```

[image]
Imagine you have two simple graphs, each with three vertices as follow. Let's consider the first graph first. If I contract vertices {1,2}, vertex 2 is deleted (rather than 1, which might be selected based on alphabetical order). As a result, the remaining edge is 1 <-> 3. However, in my opinion, since vertices {1,2} are contracted, whether the remaining edge is 1 <-> 3 or 2 <-> 3, they are essentially the same.

Similarly, for the second graph, if you contract vertices {2,3}, vertex 3 is deleted, resulting in the remaining edge 1 <-> 2. If you compare the resulting two graphs, you'll notice that they appear different. However, in reality, they are the same, and the perceived difference arises solely from how Mathematica selects which vertex to delete.

So, how can I determine that these two graphs are duplicates? It's important to note that not only the shape but also the vertex names are significant. Two graphs with the exact same structure but different vertex names should not be considered duplicates.

Below is another example with slightly more complex graphs. These two graphs should be considered duplicates, but they might not appear identical in the output "res". Consequently, I cannot automatically compare them using the "Equal" function, even though they are, in fact, the same. While these examples use numeric vertices, in my real scenarios, the vertices could also be symbols or letters.

```
graphList = {Graph[
    Range[6], { 1  \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
     4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, VertexLabels -> Automatic], 
   Graph[Range[6], {1  \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
     3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
     5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]};
contractEdgeList = {{{1, 2}, {5, 6}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 6}}};
res = MapThread[
  VertexContract[#1, #2] &, {graphList, contractEdgeList}]
```

Comment: There is the command `IsomorphicGraphQ` that should solve your problem.

Comment: @DanielHuber IsomorphicGraphQ only cares about shape/structure. For example the first example below `g` and `h` are isomorphic but they're not considered duplicates in my case as the vertice names are not same. 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IsomorphicGraphQ.html

Comment: However, in the first case above the two graphs in `res` look not same but they're actually same if you consider the contract vertices to be same. For the first graph the remaining edge is  1 <-> 3  but this should be same as  2 <-> 3 as vertices {1,2} are contracted.